# Is there anyway through which USB device know that the Data is read from endpoint buffer?

Tags: keyboard, usb, stm32, hid

I'm trying to emulate a USB Keyboard with help of STM32 USB Device Library. The host here is not a Computer/ laptop, but a custom device to which a HID keyboard can be connected. I send data using API `USBD_HID_SendReport`(); but the host doesn't seem to recognize or read it by the time I write new data via same API. If I send same data for say 7 times the host reads it for 4 times only.

So is there anyway to know that the data is being read by USB Host from the `EP` Buffer?

Shall I change the `bInterval` in endpoint descriptor, what is the standard interval used in case of all keyboards?

P.S. The same data when sent to Computer or Laptop does gets read quickly by the host.

Answer (score 3):

`USBD_HID_SendReport` only prepares the data for the next transmition when host **requires one**. It does not matter how many times you call this function. It will be send only as many times as host requested. The moment when it is send depends on the host only.

Device does not transmit anything without the host request

Comment: Will USBD_HID_SendReport() write the report/data to Endpoint buffer?